# Height and width options image css magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

> ```
>  $h= (int) Mage::getStoreConfig('mw/news/h_image');
>  $w =(int) Mage::getStoreConfig('mw/news/w_image');
>  <div class="post-items" style="height: $h; width: $w">
> ```

I know it don't work but I don't know what to do to it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be the problem:

`Mage::getStoreConfig()` is a PHP function, it has to be called inside a `<?php ?>` block and is then executed by the server.
A `<div>` is a HTML container.
If you want to send PHP-variables such as `$h` and `$w` to the browser, you must echo them.

Corrected, your code would look like this:

```
<?php
$h = (int) Mage::getStoreConfig('mw/news/h_image');
$w =(int) Mage::getStoreConfig('mw/news/w_image');
?>
<div class="post-items" style="height: <?php echo $h ?>px; width: <?php echo $w ?>px">
```

Comment: yes bro :D style="height: <?php echo $h ?>px; width: <?php echo $w ?>px"> is correct , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Mage::getStoreConfig('mw/news/w_image')` and `Mage::getStoreConfig('mw/news/w_image')` are ***system configuration value***,those field ,you have find at

***Admin>System>Configuration Section.***

Your 3rd party module have this `type code which have written at system.xml`.

system.xml is find at ***app/code/[Module_CODE_Pool]/ModuleNameSpace]/[ModuleName]/etc.***

***You can get briefly description at***

[inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/create-configuration-for-your-magento-extension/)

[excellencemagentoblog](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/22/magento-part8-series-systemxml/)

[Alan Strom Blog](http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration)

Comment: I knows but [ style = "height: $ h; width: $ w"] is not true, your alternatives?

Comment: just echo  Mage::getStoreConfig('mw/news/h_image') check that is it given value or not?